# How can I add to a class like this so I can foreach loop?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to be able to loop through all of the strings in a simple class, i.e. do the following:

```
FormDebugMetrics debugMetrics = new FormDebugMetrics();
foreach(string d in debugMetrics)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(d) {..}
    }
```

By my class is like this (without a public definition for 'GetEnumerator':

```
 public class FormDebugMetrics
    {
        public string DebugMetrics_Top { get; set; }
        public string DebugMetrics_Bottom { get; set; }
        public string DebugMetrics_Bottom { get; set; }
    }
```

How can this be done? Do I somehow add an enumerator?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
public class FormDebugMetrics : IEnumerable<string> {
    // details elided

    public string DebugMetrics_Top { get; set; }
    public string DebugMetrics_Middle { get; set; }
    public string DebugMetrics_Bottom { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator() {
        yield return this.DebugMetrics_Top;
        yield return this.DebugMetrics_Middle;
        yield return this.DebugMetrics_Bottom;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerator.GetEnumerator() {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

That said, I question your design. It's unclear without more context whether or not it's appropriate.

Comment: You actually don't have to implement IEnumerable. Simply having a GetEnumerator() method allows you to use foreach. One of the few examples of duck typing in C#

Answer (score 1):

You either need to use reflection or take a different approach. I'd look into using a Dictionary instead of using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot. At least in no simple manner.  You can add a GetEnumerator method or wrap it in another class that does know how to do this.

You could also do this via Reflection or with the C# 4.0 dynamic features but I would really really caution against that.